# jquery .on with twitter bootstrap radio buttons

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a function to setup a jQuery .on for touchstart and click events for various controls so that I can do some additional UI stuff when they're clicked.  This removes the 300ms delay on a touch device and also prevents ghost clicks (where a click is registered on touchend and onclick).

```
function touchClick(att, sel, fnc) {
    $(att).on('touchstart click', sel, function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        if (event.handled !== true) {   
            fnc(this, event);
            event.handled = true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

One of the controls I'm sending through this function is a twitter bootstrap radio button.  When I click it the fnc() is called, but the radio button doesn't update to show which radio button is active.  How can I wire this up so that the radio button is updated to reflect the user click (only once though, no ghost updates pls).

**EDIT:** Or simply, how do I call bootstrap's 'update radio button' function?

Comment: One simple answer to this would be to say how I can call twitter bootstrap's update radio button function.

Comment: You may need to use a hidden form element. See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XYEjs/32/

Comment: That's not a bad idea actually - thanks.